# Will the Microsoft-Teams bot get any event when bot is added by editing an existing message?

Tags: microsoft-teams

When a Microsoft-teams bot is added to an existing message on a channel, by editing the message, would it be possible to notify the bot about the message?

I tried this scenario and looks like bot is not receiving any events for such cases. Is there any interface or mechanism available to notify the bot about the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit a Teams message and add any @ mention - whether it's to a user or a bot - it doesn't generate new notifications. This has been a gap ever since we added the ability to edit messages.